# How to bind class input properties to an animation file of Component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a custom Modal Component, with an animation file too,
some basic angular version-11 animations, for :enter and :leave
when the modal leaves and enters the DOM, now for reusability and
customization i want to be able to pass the Component some custom
inputs values, and from the component typescript file bind those
input values to the animation file i mean read them and use them in the animations,

So the Component Modal behaves accordingly according to the input values in term of animation and transition on :enter and on :leave the DOM
for example

```
trigger('animationForModal', [
     transition(':enter', [
     style({
     opacity: 0,
  // here for transform i want to read the value from typescript file
     transform: 'translateY({{ inputValue }})',
   }),
```

I hope i explained well my intension

Comment: Use @Hostbinding('animationForModal') get inputValue() { return yourvalue}

Comment: I tried like that but it's not working